# Debian 10: activating bridge interface on remote host freezes ssh connection

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge, freeze

I am working on a fresh installed Debian Buster installation on a remote host located in a data center elsewhere.

I have a script ready to copy the working standard /etc/network/interfaces back in place and reboot with an *at* command entry should a problem arise altering the network configuration.

When i add a bridge br0 entry into the /etc/network/interfaces and call ifup br0, the bridge interface appears as follows:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xxx.62.204  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast xx.xxx.62.255
        inet6 xxxx::7a2b:cbff:fe71:b0b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 78:xx:xx:xx:b0:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1722  bytes 80621 (78.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5  bytes 426 (426.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xxx.62.204  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast xx.xxx.62.255
        ether 78:xx:xx:xx:b0:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27871902  bytes 1784816339 (1.6 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10682  bytes 1326822 (1.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 26  bytes 3455 (3.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26  bytes 3455 (3.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

with this /etc/network/interfaces entry:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address xx.xxx.62.204
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network xx.xxx.62.0
        broadcast xx.xxx.62.255
        gateway xx.xxx.62.254

iface eno1 inet6 static
        address xxxx:198:ff0d:e800::/40
        pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eno1/accept_dad
        post-up ip -6 route add default via xxxx:198:ff00::1
        up ip -6 addr add xxxx:198:ff0d:e800::1/40 dev $IFACE
        down ip -6 addr del xxxx:198:ff0d:e800::1/40 dev $IFACE


auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address xx.xxx.62.204
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway xx.xxx.62.254
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

But after a few seconds the ssh connection freezes, a ping packet no longer arrives and i have to wait for the emergency script to repair/reboot.

The whole attempt is to provide a kvm virtual machine on the host with a bridge interface to have access to the outside world via a separate IP4 address.

The added bridge entry is according to [this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/767644/how-to-connect-kvm-virtual-machines-directly-to-external-ips)